# about speed of script running by server

Tags: php, performance, web-applications, web-crawler, bandwidth

I have a slow internet connection, like 128k. If I write a script which would get 100 pages from another website and put its contents in my database with curl or anything else, it would take ages to leech all 100 pages.

```
$get = file_get_contents("www.google.com?search=something");
$res = pareser::parse()$get; 
foreach($res as $r )
{
    $db->insert($r['title']);
}
```

But what if I use AJAX and send a AJAX request to my server to activate my spider? My server speed is much faster then my client speed, and it's the server who runs the script now (at least i think!). Why it doesn't make much different in speed of leeching those 100 pages though?

Comment: Isn't your PHP script running on your server anyway?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, 128K IS the speed of your connection and you cannot make it faster with PHP
2. You will get banned from google pretty soon and CAPTCHA will be shown instead of actual results

Comment: thank you , in some leech scripts like rapid leech the server is doing the leech part and it's very very fast . what i ment was isn't that using ajax is knda samse thing ?